# How to compute the Class Interval Arithmetic Mean?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a program that computes the class interval arithmetic mean but there is a little bit error in its error...

For example:
I will input (10-20,21-30) in my interval_Values and i will input(1,2) in my frequency_values and the computation goes this way:

```
((10+20)/2),((21+30)/2)
```

and it will give

```
15,25.5
```

then again it will multiply these values to the value of frequency_Values

```
(15*1)+(25.5*2)
```

and this will give the result of

```
(15+51)=66
```

and after these. It will going to divide 66 to the sum of the frequency_Values which is

```
(1+3)
```

So

```
66/3=22
```

In my program when i input these values, it gives the result of 15. What would be the error.

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView interval_Values = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.interval_Values);
   final AutoCompleteTextView frequency_Values = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.frequency_Values);
    final TextView txtSummation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSummation);
    final TextView txtArithmetic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArithmetic);

    Button btncalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btncalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] interval = interval_Values.getText().toString().split(",");
            String[] frequency= frequency_Values.getText().toString().split(",");
            double [] x = new double[interval.length];
            double [] y = new double[frequency.length];

            double freq=0;
            double xy=0;
            double result=0;

            for(int j=0;j<interval.length;j++){
                String[] intr=interval[j].split("-");
                x[j]=Double.parseDouble(intr[j]);

                double midpoint=((x[0])+(x[1]))/2;

                y[j]=Double.parseDouble(frequency[j]);
                freq+=y[j];
                xy+=midpoint*y[j];
                result =xy/freq;

            }
            txtArithmetic.setText(Double.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

After Thinking many times i came up with this codes that answers the above question...i hope it will help:)

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView interval_Values = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.interval_Values);
    final AutoCompleteTextView frequency_Values = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.frequency_Values);
    final TextView txtSummation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSummation);
    final TextView txtArithmetic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArithmetic);

    Button btncalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btncalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] interval = interval_Values.getText().toString().split(",");
            String[] frequency= frequency_Values.getText().toString().split(",");
            double [] freq=new double[frequency.length];




            double xy=0;
            double y=0;
            double midpoint=0;
            for(int j=0;j<interval.length;j++){
                String intr[]=interval[j].split("-");
                  midpoint=(Double.parseDouble(intr[0]) + Double.parseDouble(intr[1]))/2;
                freq[j]=Double.parseDouble(frequency[j]);
                y+=freq[j];
                xy+=midpoint*freq[j];

            }

            txtSummation.setText(xy+"/"+y);
            double result=xy/y;
            txtArithmetic.setText(Double.toString(result));

        }
        });
```